# wp_user_create - Setting a role - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, roles

In this custom plugin I'm developing I use the function wp_user_create(); to add a user.
I want to set a specified role because now they are all being added as 'subscribers'.
Is it possible to afterwards set the newly created users user role to e.g. 'editor' or 'author' or any custom made role?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `wp_insert_user()` you are able to apply additional parameters such as the user's role, when creating a new user.

```
wp_insert_user( array ( 'role' => 'editor', ... ) );
```

For more information take a look in the [**Wordpress Codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user).

Answer (score 19):

Yes you can add user role after creating user as below

```
$user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );
$user_id_role = new WP_User($user_id);
$user_id_role->set_role('contributor');
```